# Battle pass quest disconnect

Tags: dota-2

Does a victory count for a battle pass quest when the game is safe to leave for connection issues ?

Seems like every time I get a decent team someone on the other team leave at start .

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not count. It's the same behavior as it is with the *win* itself.